# Can I attach a .NET TraceListener to an externally running process?

Tags: .net, tracelistener

I am developing an application scheduling program that will run other applications using System.Diagnostics.Process.  The external applications are of various types (some .NET and some not).  For those external apps that have trace logging enabled, is there a way that I can attach the tracelistener of the parent/calling application to listen to and record all the trace output from the child/called application to the parent application's trace output?

This is not primarily for debugging purposes.  This is more to track trace output from all the various scheduled applications by collecting it into one place as much as possible.

The scheduler app is still in the early design stages, but will be .NET, and I'm trying to clear up potential design issues before I get into it too far.

To clarify a little: I need a solution that can be an integrated part of the scheduler app in .NET code.  I cannot have any dependencies on an external application for capturing the trace.

Comment: you can use DebugView for that. It can handle all Trace messages form .net and unmanaged apps. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Comment: No, I need a solution that can be an integrated part of the scheduler application and will not require being dependent on another application running. Not to mention having to capture, parse and store a log file which may result in lost trace data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I attach a trace listener to a running process?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290543/how-do-i-attach-a-trace-listener-to-a-running-process)