# How to get Trace from another windows app?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, trace

I'm using Trace.Listeners for my applications like this:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
```

or

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
```

But what if I want to get a trace from another windows application? I know there is a dbg view for this, but can I implement this myself in my code via c# and .net?

Paraphrase. How i can read trace from win debugger?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290543/how-do-i-attach-a-trace-listener-to-a-running-process.

Comment: I don't think so, besides the marked answer does not answer my question in any way and is definitely not a solution.